# ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to create two tables and at the same time i am trying to link them together using foreign and primary keys. However I successfully create my parent table ( Student with primary key ) but failed to create child table ( Attendence with foreign key ).

**What is the problem ?**

I get the following error while creating Attendence table:

***ERROR at line 5: ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here***

**My code:**

*Student table:*

```
create table Student (

            ST_ROLLNO  NUMBER(6) constraint s_pk primary key,
            ST_NAME    VARCHAR(30) not null,
            ST_ADDRESS  varchar(35) not null
);
```

*Attendence table:*

```
create table Attendence (

            ST_ROLLNO  NUMBER(6),
            ST_DATE    VARCHAR(30) not null,
            ST_PRESENT_ABSENT  varchar(1) not null,
            constraint f_pk Attendence.ST_ROLLNO foreign key references Student(ST_ROLLNO)
);
```

Comment: A column name is "simple" if it is not qualified with a table name. Constraints, at least in Oracle, cannot span across tables; an out-of-line constraint, like you are defining, must be on a column (or combination of columns) in the same table you are defining. So it makes no sense to qualify the name or names of the constrained column(s) with the table name (which is understood); and the syntax prohibits it, to make it crystal clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [foreign key constraint syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/constraint.htm#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE__CJABCJJF) is wrong; it should be:

```
constraint f_pk foreign key (ST_ROLLNO) references Student(ST_ROLLNO)
```

You are preceding the FK column name with the table name, which is wrong in itself, but also have it in the wrong place.

```
create table Student (

            ST_ROLLNO  NUMBER(6) constraint s_pk primary key,
            ST_NAME    VARCHAR(30) not null,
            ST_ADDRESS  varchar(35) not null
);  

Table STUDENT created.

create table Attendence (

            ST_ROLLNO  NUMBER(6),
            ST_DATE    VARCHAR(30) not null,
            ST_PRESENT_ABSENT  varchar(1) not null,
            constraint f_pk foreign key (ST_ROLLNO) references Student(ST_ROLLNO)
);

Table ATTENDENCE created.
```

Comment: Do you know how to perform DML operation on a table whoes column is type obeject ?

Comment: @Ahtisham - yes, but that doesn't have anything to do with this question. There are plenty of examples around, depending on exactly what you're doing (including [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADOBJ/Sql-object-types-and-references.htm#ADOBJ7070)), but if you try to follow those and can't make it work then you'll need to ask a new question.

Comment: Or you can include the FK in the column definition and inherit the datatype: `st_rollno constraint f_pk references student(st_rollno)`.

Comment: @AlexPoole Change `ST_PRESENT_ABSENT varchar(35)` to `ST_PRESENT_ABSENT varchar(1)` I changed it in question.

Comment: @Ahtisham - that's irrelevant to the issue you were having, and won't ever help anyone else.. but OK... Changing the question after it's been answered is pointless anyway though (or even rude for more substantial changes than this).

Comment: @AlexPoole Okay sorry! May peace be with you :)

Answer (score 5):

According to oracle documentation,

[**ORA ERR**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96525/e1500.htm)

*ORA-01748 only simple column names allowed here*

> The following is the cause of this error:
>
> This SQL statement does not allow a qualified column name, such as
>   username.table.column or table.column.
>
> Action you can take to resolve this issue: Remove the qualifications
>   from the column and retry the operation.

In your case, you are trying to refer to the table name while defining a constraint -

`Attendence.ST_ROLLNO` - *WRONG*.

It must contain a simple name without the table name or schema name.

Comment: Sir do you know how to perform DML operation on a table whoes column is type obeject ?

Comment: @Ahtisham : It is too broad question and not in the scope of a comment section of an unrelated answer.  You may google it  or ask that as a separate question providing the details. And you don't have to address me as "Sir"  the next time.